# How to change Total Item Value in ng-grid and pagination problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am working with  ng-grid . It's work fine.
but value of "Total Item" is display only current page item length.
I need to show a total array item length not only current page item length.

My array size is 55
My page size is : 15
Then display Total Item is 15.
but I need : Total Item is 55 .

Another problem is::

ng-grid pagination not able to click "last" button
and  "next" button move to one extra page..

```
                $scope.filterOptions = {
                        filterText: "",
                        useExternalFilter: true
                    };
                    $scope.pagingOptions = {
                        pageSizes: [5,15, 25, 50],
                        pageSize: 15,
                       currentPage: 1
                    };      
                         $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){    
                        var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
                        $scope.myData = pagedData;
                        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }
                    };        
                     $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {    
                         setTimeout(function () {    
                            var data;    
                            if (searchText) {    
                                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();    
                                $scope.setPagingData($scope.allalert,page,pageSize);
                            } else {
                                alert=[[],[]];
                                service.getallalert(accountid)
                                .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
                                        var len=data.all_alert.length;

                                        var lenmessage=0;
                                        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                                            $scope.devicenameinalert=data.all_alert[i].devicename;
                                            lenmessage=data.all_alert[i].message_list.length;

                                            if(lenmessage!=0){
                                                for(var j=0;j<lenmessage;j++){

                                                    alert.push(data.all_alert[i].message_list[j]);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        $scope.allalert=alert;
                                        $scope.allalert.splice(0,2);

                                        if($scope.allalert.length==0){
                                            toaster.pop("error", "Not Found", "Record Not Found.");
                                        }else{
                                            $scope.setPagingData($scope.allalert,page,pageSize);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .error(function(data,status,headers,config)
                                            {
                                            });     
                            }
                        }, 100);
                    };



                       $scope.gridOptions = {        

                        data: 'myData', selectedItems: [] ,
                        enablePaging: true,
                        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
                        showFooter: true, 
                        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
                        plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()]
                    };
                    $scope.selectedCityInfo = [];
                    $scope.gridOptions.enableRowSelection = true;
                    $scope.gridOptions.showSelectionCheckbox = true;
                    $scope.gridOptions.multiSelect = true;
                    $scope.gridOptions.showSelectionCheckbox=true;
                    $scope.gridOptions.showColumnMenu = false;
                    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = 'gridColumnDefs';

                    $scope.gridColumnDefs = [ {field:'devicename',cellTemplate: '<div class="margincenter"><center>{{row.entity.devicename}}</center></div>',headerCellTemplate: '<div class="textCenter">Device Name</div>'},
                                              {field:'alerttime',displayName: 'Date/Time'},
                                              {field:'message',displayName: 'Message'}
                                              ];
```

Comment: show your options for grid, some code or jsfiddle with [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you're using ng-grid 3.0+ (now ui-grid) you should check out their example on pagination here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination. There they have a grid set up with the total number of records showing correctly. If that isn't helpful could you please post a fiddle or at least the gridOptions object so we can get a better idea of the problem? Thanks.

Comment: thanks Brandon...  i am not use ui-grid